# How to include whitespaces in .match() javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code to check for standard characters:

```
if(modelName.match(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,40}$/)){
//safe
}
else{
//not so safe    
}
```

How can I add whitespaces to the match criteria?

Comment: By adding whitespace to the match criteria? You could google for "whitespace regexp", the first result for which is [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html), which says, "`\s` stands for "whitespace character".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if(modelName.match(/^[0-9a-zA-Z ]{1,40}$/)){
```

or

```
if(modelName.match(/^[0-9a-zA-Z\s]{1,40}$/)){
```